# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM' in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please help me in the code, I get an error

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'

```
SELECT 
    produkt.Twr_Kod as kod,
    (SELECT
         ISNULL(SUM(zasoby.TwZ_Ilosc), 0) + ISNULL(SUM(trs_ilosc), 0) 
     FROM
         cdn.TraSElem 
     WHERE
         trs_typ = 3 AND TrS_TrEIdWydania = 0 
         AND TrS_DataOpe > GETDATE() AND zasoby.TwZ_TwrId = TrS_TwrId 
         AND zasoby.TwZ_MagId = 1
     FROM 
         CDN.TwrZasoby as zasoby
     WHERE 
         zasoby.Twz_TwrId = product.Twr_twrid) AS zasoby,
    CONVERT(NUMERIC(10, 0), produkt.Twr_IloscMin) AS ilosc_minimalna
FROM
    CDN.Towary AS product
LEFT JOIN 
    CDN.Towary AS produkt ON product.Twr_TwrId = produkt.Twr_TwrId
GROUP BY 
    product.Twr_TwrId, produkt.Twr_Kod, produkt.Twr_IloscMin
ORDER BY 
    kod
```

Comment: That "inner" `SELECT` (the second "column" of your outer column list) has **two** `FROM` and `WHERE` clauses.... either you're missing some parenthesis or something, or you're just mixing code that doesn't conform to the T-SQL specs....

Comment: `CONVERT(NUMERIC(10, 0), produkt.Twr_IloscMin) AS ilosc_minimalna` in WHERE?

Comment: Why do you have a `GROUP By` with no aggregation as well?

Comment: Count `(` and `)`. Same number?

Answer (score 1):

SQLs kinda need to look like this:

```
SELECT columns FROM tables_or_queries WHERE predicates GROUP BY grouping_keys ORDER BY columns
```

This pattern can be nested both inside the SELECT region and the FROM region:

```
SELECT
  column1,
  (SELECT columnA FROM table WHERE where_predicates) as column2,
  column3
FROM
  table
  INNER JOIN
  (SELECT columnA, columnB FROM table WHERE where_predicates) as nested_query
  ON join_predicates
WHERE
  where_predicates
```

But you can't have multiple FROM regions etc.. To get more targeted advice youre going to have to tell us what you're hoping your query does.. Right now, we can only say to sort out the basic syntax errors the compilation process is complaining about

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have multiple FROM statements in a single SELECT statement.  Every SELECT can have only one FROM clause. Glancing through your query, I think it's going to give you performance nightmares. Use joins instead of using inline queries. Will improve performance.

```
SELECT 
    produkt.Twr_Kod as kod,
    (SELECT
         ISNULL(SUM(zasoby.TwZ_Ilosc), 0) + ISNULL(SUM(trs_ilosc), 0) 
     **FROM
         cdn.TraSElem 
     WHERE
         trs_typ = 3 AND TrS_TrEIdWydania = 0 
         AND TrS_DataOpe > GETDATE() AND zasoby.TwZ_TwrId = TrS_TwrId 
         AND zasoby.TwZ_MagId = 1
     FROM 
         CDN.TwrZasoby as zasoby**
     WHERE 
         zasoby.Twz_TwrId = product.Twr_twrid) AS zasoby,
    CONVERT(NUMERIC(10, 0), produkt.Twr_IloscMin) AS ilosc_minimalna
FROM
    CDN.Towary AS product
LEFT JOIN 
    CDN.Towary AS produkt ON product.Twr_TwrId = produkt.Twr_TwrId
GROUP BY 
    product.Twr_TwrId, produkt.Twr_Kod, produkt.Twr_IloscMin
ORDER BY 
    kod
```